# Cannot get Ubuntu 13.04 to load

Tags: 12.04, installation, upgrade, 13.04

I tried the automatic update, and it quit less than half way though.  Now 12 won't load without going through advanced options.  I installed 13 on a separate partition, but from the loader, I get nothing but a flashing cursor and then a blank black screen.  Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I install Ubuntu with two partitions, one for '/' to hold the system which I can easily format and re-install incase a problem crops up, and the rest of the drive assigned to '/home' to hold my files and settings so that I do not lose anything during a fresh install...  I'd recommend doing this with a fresh install after backing up your files...

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to guess what may have gone wrong, but among other things, there is a remote possibility that your boot menu is is out of sync with what is actually on your system. This can happen if you re-partition, upgrade, etc.

To be sure that your GRUB menu is still pointing to the right places you can run `sudo update-grub`. This will rebuild your boot menu from whatever systems are found on your computer.